# Pinning addin for OWA

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

We are currently running into issues where a specific add-in has to be manually pinned for our users specifically in OWA 365. I've been digging through forums to find a PowerShell script to pin the specific add-in, but haven't had any luck. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thank you for your time,

We have not tried much with PowerShell, since I'm fairly vanilla with the syntax with O365. We re ran the configuration in the 365 admin console to see if that would just pin it. The result was the same, some users had the Add-in pinned some did not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that pinned-by-default is something that can be configured in the add-in manifest, but not after the deployment like via powershell

Comment: By Pinning do you mean pinning the Addin in toolbar or pinning the taskpane?

Answer (score 0):

There is no PowerShell command for pinning Office add-ins (task panes). The best what you could do is to specify the following in the manifest file:

```
 <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
```

Only users can pin add-ins manually in Office applications.